# Backward Euler's Equation approximation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations

In the paper [Simulating Spatial Partial Differential Equations with Cellular Automata](http://www.r2labs.org/pubs/strader-biocomp09.pdf), I found an approximation for the Backward Euler's Equation using a first order Taylor series, namely equation (8) on page 3:
$$
u_{i+1,j}=u_{i,j}+\frac{h_t f(u_{i,j})}{1-h_t\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}|_{i,j}}\qquad(8).
$$

I am wondering how to get this.

First of all, the backward Euler's equation is
$$
u_{i+1,j}=u_{i,j}+h_tf(u_{i+1,j})\qquad (*).
$$
Now, I guess the authors have delevoped $f(u_{i+1,j})$ in a Taylor series of first order in $(i,j)$ what should be
$$
f(u_{i+1,j})\approx f(u_{i,j})+h_t \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}(i,j)\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(i,j).
$$

Putting this into $(*)$, we get
$$
u_{i+1,j}=u_{i,j}+h_t\cdot\left[f(u_{i,j})+h_t\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}(i,j)\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(i,j)\right]
$$

Does this lead to (8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable $h_t$ is sufficiently small then
$$
\left( 1-h_t \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}(i,j) \right)^{-1} = 1 + h_t \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}(i,j) + \mathcal{O}(h_t^2).
$$
Noting that $f(u) = \partial u / \partial t$ by definition, this implies that within the accuracy of the scheme, the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!!